# Have 2 ID! variables but only want to use one

Tags: variables, graphql, null, graphql-js

I am writing a graphQL query and have 2 `ID!` fields. But only want to use one. I am getting an error if I remove the `!`. Is there a way to use a graphQL query with just 1 of the ID's

My query:

```
query getData($tableID: ID, $viewID: ID) {
  table(id: $tableID) {
    id
    name
  }
  view(id: $viewID) {
    id
    name
  }
}
```

On Postman, it is giving me an error that says `ID!` is required. But I only want `view` information in this case. Is that possible? Is there a way to pass:

```
{
viewID: "123"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're querying two different objects by ID. Either you only really want to query one in which case:

```
query getData($viewID: ID) {
  view(id: $viewID) {
    id
    name
  }
}
```

Or (unlikely given the type names) you want to query both using the same parameter in which case:

```
query getData($oneID: ID) {
  table(id: $oneID) {
    id
    name
  }
  view(id: $oneID) {
    id
    name
  }
}
```